# Drawing $4$ cards from a standard deck without replacement, what is the chance that you get at least $1$ red card and at least $1$ black card?

Tags: probability

I'm little stuck with this question, the answer shows $$1-2\left(\frac{26}{52}\right)\left(\frac{25}{51}\right)\left(\frac{24}{50}\right)\left(\frac{23}{49}\right)$$

However, shouldn't the probability simply be $$1-p(\text{all cards are of one color})=1-\left(\frac{26}{52}\right)\left(\frac{25}{51}\right)\left(\frac{24}{50}\right)\left(\frac{23}{49}\right)?$$ If we get the probability of not all cards are the same color, doesn't that mean we satisfy what this question is asking for?

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you propose corresponds to, say, the probability that not all cards are black. But we also want that not all cards are red.

Comment: isn't the compliment of P(all cards are the same ) = not all cards are the same?

Comment: That is true. And all cards can be the same in two ways. Either all black, or all red. That's where the 2 comes from in the answer from your book.

Comment: ahhh I see it now thanks!